# removing bias from neural network layer

Tags: python, lasagne, nolearn

I want to remove the bias parameter. I tried to include `thebias=None` where I define my neural net, but it didn't work.

```
net1 = NeuralNet(
layers=[ # three layers: one hidden layer
('input', layers.InputLayer),
#('hidden', layers.DenseLayer),
('output', layers.DenseLayer),
],
# layer parameters:
input_shape=(None,2), # 2 inputs
#hidden_num_units=200, # number of units in hidden layer
output_nonlinearity=None, # output layer uses identity function
output_num_units=1, # 1 target value

# optimization method:
update=nesterov_momentum,
update_learning_rate=0.01,
update_momentum=0.9,

regression=True,  # flag to indicate we're dealing with regression problem
max_epochs=400,  # we want to train this many epochs
verbose=1,
bias = None
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Build the network yourself
inputs = InputLayer(shape=(None, 2))
network = DenseLayer(inputs, num_units=1, nonlinearity=None, b = None)

net1 = NeuralNet(
network,
#We don't need any of these parameters since we provided them above
# layer parameters:
#input_shape=(None,2), # 2 inputs
#hidden_num_units=200, # number of units in hidden layer
#output_nonlinearity=None, # output layer uses identity function
#output_num_units=1, # 1 target value

# optimization method:
update=nesterov_momentum,
update_learning_rate=0.01,
update_momentum=0.9,

regression=True,  # flag to indicate we're dealing with regression problem
max_epochs=400,  # we want to train this many epochs
verbose=1,
bias = None
)
```

I think this should work. There might be a kwarg to pass in the network (I can't remember) but I think it's by default the first parameter if nothing's given.

Comment: I remember where I saw this... in the source code :) : https://gist.github.com/dnouri/fe855653e9757e1ce8c4#file-nntoy-py-L24

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Lasagne Documentation for conv layers](http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/layers/conv.html) (it's similar for dense layers), you have the following option for the biases:

```
b = None
```

At least according to the Lasagne documentation, there doesn't seem to be a "bias" parameter for any of the layers, they instead use "b". I cannot speak for NoLearn as I do not use that package.

Edit:

Here is some Lasagne example code:

```
import lasagne
net = {}
net['input'] = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 3, 224,224), input_var=None)
net['conv'] = lasagne.layers.Conv2DLayer(net['input'], num_filters=5, filter_size=3, b = None)
print net['conv'].get_params()
```

Returns:

```
[W]
```

alone, meaning there is no bias term.

For NoLearn I am not sure as I do not use that package.

Comment: when using 'b=None', I get 'ValueError: Unused kwarg: b'

Comment: I have updated my answer with some sample Lasagne code. I do not use NoLearn. I am providing a Lasagne answer because you included the Lasagne tag for your question. Hopefully this is still useful for you.